# Weak form of Berry-Esséen theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, integration, random-variables

Let $X$ (a real random variable) have mean zero, unit variance and finite third moment. Let $Z_{n}:=(X_{1}+...+X_{n})/\sqrt{n}$, where $X_{1}, ... X_{n}$ are iid copies of $X$. According to the Berry-Esséen theorem we have:

${\bf{P}}(Z_{n}<a )={\bf{P}}(G<a)+O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(E|X|^3))$

uniformly for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, where $G\equiv N(0,1)_{\mathbb{R}}$, and the implied constant is absolute.

From this I want to deduce the following weak form of the Berry-Esséen theorem:

Let $\phi$ be smooth with uniformly bounded derivatives up to third order. Let $X,X_{n}, Z_{n}$ be as above. Then:

${\bf{E}}\phi(Z_{n})={\bf{E}}\phi(G)+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(E|X|^3)\displaystyle \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\phi'''(x)|\right)$.

According to my textbook this deduction is easily seen by integration by parts. Unfortunately I do not manage ti see how to do this...

Comment: Do you have a link to the textbook you consider? There are maybe additional assumptions which can help.

Comment: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/#more-3281 Below thm5 there is the claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can consider $N$ of standard normal distribution and independent of the sequence $(X_n,n\geqslant 1)$. Then we can use Taylor's formula at order three, bound the remainder. Then indeed the computation of the terms associated to $\phi(N)$, $\phi'(N)$, etc... can be done by integrations by parts.

Here are more details: we have 
$$\phi(Z_n)=\phi(N)+(Z_n-N)\phi'(N)+\frac{(Z_n-N)^2}2\phi''(N)+(Z_n-N)^3\frac{\phi^{(3)}(\theta_n)}6,$$
where $\theta_n$ is a number between $Z_n$ and $N$ (where $\omega$ is fixed). Now, taking the expectation, we get 
$$\mathbb E(\phi(Z_n))=\mathbb E\left[\phi(N)\right]+\mathbb E\left[(Z_n-N)\phi'(N)\right]+\mathbb E\left[\frac{(Z_n-N)^2}2\phi''(N)\right]+\mathbb E\left[(Z_n-N)^3\frac{\phi^{(3)}(\theta_n)}6\right].$$

Using independence, it remains only terms of the form $\mathbb E\left[N^p\phi^{(k)}(N)\right]$ and the last one.

Comment: So you take Taylor's formula for $\phi$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hmm, could you just add some more details. Then I accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @D.Giraudo: I am extremely grateful!

Comment: @Giraudo: Now that I have time to reconsider this question, I am pretty sure that the argument you gave cannot work. The RHS can simply not converge in general. How do you want to conclude, and what to integrate by parts? Could you pleases reconsider your answer.

Comment: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/254a-notes-2-the-central-limit-theorem/#more-3281 below thm5 there is the claim.